# How to locate the x, y coordinates of text on the screen?

Tags: python, robotframework, ui-automation, pyautogui

I am trying to find the x, y coordinates of a web element (part of the web page that's open on screen) and some automated tests using the `robotframework` are being run on it.

I'd like to provide the function with the text string, and get (x, y) coordinates returned.

I am not sure if I can do this in `pyautogui`.

Environment: Chrome / OS X

EDIT:

I am wondering if I can use `locateOnScreen()` function in this library to locate text, (but it seems it's only for images according to the [documentation](http://pyautogui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/screenshot.html#the-locate-functions))?

Comment: Please read [ask]. Please provide the code you have tried and the execution result including any error messages, etc.

Answer (score 3):

**Web elements** has property **.location** which return dictionary of x and y coordinates of the element.

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome('/path/to/chromedriver')
elem = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//xpath_to_the_element')
loc = elem.location
print(loc)
```

Above code will return something like :

```
{'x' : 123, 'y' : 234}
```

Comment: I was actually looking into the selenium find_element_by_ functions. It seemed that I had to launch a new chrome window by doing driver.get("www.abc.com"). Is there a way to call the the find_element_by_ function on a chrome window that's already open?

Comment: @rocketfinger Selenium won't be able to get a handle of the browser that was opened by a user, not using the webdriver

Comment: What if the other window is opened by [Open Browser](http://robotframework.org/Selenium2Library/Selenium2Library.html#Open%20Browser) keyword in Selenium2Library? I.e. it's been opened by the webdriver, but not through that python script.

Comment: Selenium can only access windows that it has opened.

Comment: That is technically possible by connecting to the webdriver's listening port, with Firefox up to v47 - I.e. no marrionette; I am doing it right now (saves A LOT of time in starting the browser, login and etc. during tests development). Still haven't found a way it greater versions ot with other proxied browsers (chrome). But that hasn't anything to do with the original question.

Comment: I am wondering if I can use locateOnScreen() function in this library to locate texts, but it seems it's only for images?
http://pyautogui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/screenshot.html